# Slicing data frame equally and store as different name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I have a **5745 data** and wish to divide it into **24** equal set. I used df_split = np.array_split(df, 24) which return me like this[image]

I need to run a function of all the data and return me 24 output. Each of the datframe has 240 data for 24 set. For example, i wish to calculate the average for first 240 data and store as **X**.

My final output should be like **X = [3,4,3,5,7,8...]**. Where 3 is the average of first 240 data(df[0]), and 4 is second 240 data(df[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxnC2.png)). Continuous for 24 set.

Comment: Average of what? What is 3, 4, 3, ...?

Comment: its the average of first 240 data, Eg: the data looks like this [1,2,3,0,1,-4,-3,2,...] and the average is 3. Then store it inside X. Then continue calculate for second 240 data.

Comment: But it doesn't? You have 5 columns... so you want to do the same thing for all 5 columns?

Comment: Yes. For example, I need to calculate the df['Close'] average for all 24 set. So the X is just the average of the df['Close']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to split your DataFrame - because you'd have to calculate the mean individually for each split. Use `groupby`, and you can do this a lot simpler:

```
n = 24
size = np.ceil(len(df) / n).astype(int)

X = df.groupby(df.index % size).mean()
```

If you want the mean for a single column, you can do so:

```
X = df.groupby(df.index % size)['Close'].mean()
```

Or, as a list:

```
X = df.groupby(df.index % size)['Close'].mean().values.tolist()
```

Comment: I need to split it as it is sorted according to date, so i have to split 24 years of data. So the X should be in sequence as well

Comment: @JackKoh well, if it was sorted to begin with, then using groupby won't change that